# Load balancers and SQL backups

Tags: mysql, apache, backup, load-balancing

Our production environments typically consists in 4-8 Apache web servers and 2 (My)SQL servers :

- Each web server is affiliated to one SQL server
- SQL servers have a circular replication setup
- All web servers are load balanced, by Pound for example.

Every night a job backups one of the SQL servers, locking the affiliated web servers for about 10-15 minutes.

Is there a way to configure the balancing to avoid reaching those locked servers for a short time?

Is there another way to handle this lock, other than backuping a non-production third server?

PS: We envisage to reload the Pound configuration, just before and after the backup, with an appropriate configuration file, but it feels a bit odd...

Comment: it appears that pound is able to detect a server fail and redistribute the load accordingly until the server is detected as working again. Can't you simply switch off the connection between pound and the server while backing up, so that it appears down to pound?

Comment: Pond only knows the 4 web servers affiliated to the backuping SQL server. I indeed may shut the web-sql communication so that the web servers itself respond a failure to the LB but it'll bounce to another potentially affiliated server and generate a lot of noisy errors before it bounces forward to a responding server... At first glance, not a bad idea, but very noisy in terms of error logs. That's a problem for us.

Comment: If one of you closer guys had the courtesy to tell me where — meaning on which SE site — I should have posted this question, it'd be of great help. Thanks a lot

Comment: I think that either unix or serverfault could have been good candidates. perhaps askubuntu if you use that distro.

Comment: Definitely on serverfault, since the question is totally platform independant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `poundctl` to disable and reenable the backend server? It must be run locally (the command protocol uses unix sockets), but you could probably have it launched remotely through an ssh session.

From the man page:

> OPTIONS
>
> [...]
>
> -B/-b n m r
>
> ```
>       Enable/disable a back-end. A disabled back-end will not be passed requests to answer. Note however that existing sessions may still cause requests to be sent their way.
> ```
>
> -n n m k
>
> ```
>       Remove a session from service m in listener n. The session key is k.
> ```

Comment: This is probably better and cleaner than reloading a alternative configuration file. For triggering, i'd rather use a local cron table.

Comment: ah, good idea, as long as the backup takes a predictable amount of time, both tasks could be run separately.